# Specific user info from facebook using passport-facebook

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport-facebook

I am using passport-facebook for OAuth and get user information from facebook. But all I am getting is some basic information (i.e. firstname, familyname). I want information like userEmail and friendList.

My current FacebookStrategy is -

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
      clientID: configAuth.facebookAuth.appID,
      clientSecret: configAuth.facebookAuth.appSecret,
      callbackURL: configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackUrl
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      process.nextTick(function() {
        User.findOne({'facebook.id': profile.id}, function(err, user) {
          if(err)
            return done(err);
          if(user)
            return done(null, user);
          else {
            var newUser = new User;
            console.log(profile);
            newUser.facebook.id = profile.id;
            newUser.facebook.token = accessToken;
            newUser.facebook.name = profile. displayName;
            newUser.save(function(err) {
              if(err)
                throw err;
              return done(null, newUser);
            })
          }
        })
      })
    }
  ));
```

Can someone tell me how can I get user's email or friend-list.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need email and user_friends you will have to add them to the scope while requesting for facebook-auth. I guess adding following code to yowill help you:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : ['email,user_friends'] }));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I worked half for me. When I saw the request for auth there was something saying my app is requesting for email and friend-list permission. But I got the friend list, not the email. So can you please tell me how can I get the email?

Comment: As friend_list, email also comes a an array. I think you will have to do this - `var email = profile.emails[0].value;` to get the email. You can also get all the email added to the account as an array if you want `var email = profile.emails;`.